# Appsync subscription filtering not working when nested response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
type Mutation {
    createEvent(input: CreateEventInput!): CreateEventPayload
}

type Subscription {
    onCreateEvent(filter: EventFilter): CreateEventPayload
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createEvent"])
}

type CreateEventPayload {
    event: Event
    clientMutationId: String
}

type Event implements Node {
    description: String
    eventName: String!
    id: String!
    status: String!
}

interface Node {
    nodeId: ID!
}

input EventFilter {
    description: StringFilter
    eventName: StringFilter
    id: StringFilter
    status: StringFilter
}
```

What I want to do is subscribe to any event that has the same id when mutation executed.

For example here is my subscription:

```
subscription MySub {
  onCreateEvent(filter: {id: {equalTo: "xxx"}}) {
    event {
      id
      eventName
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my Mutation:

```
mutation {
  createEvent(input: {aiEvent: {id: "xxx", eventName: "USER_ENTRY", status: "1"}}) {
    event {
      id
      eventName
    }
  }
}
```

After I fired Mutation, it gave me the expected result as below:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createEvent": {
      "event": {
        "id": "xxx",
        "eventName": "USER_ENTRY",

      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is not firing the subscription, is it because my `id` is eventually nested under type `event` and the response of Mutation is `CreateEventPayload` while the type `event` is nested under it?

Does the filtering accept nested field or is there something else I did wrong?